# Equivalence in Algebraic Manifolds (Variety)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $V\subset A$ be a nonempty variety. Show that the following are equivalent:

$i)$ $V$ is a point.

$ii)$ $\Gamma (V)=K$

$iii)$ $\dim_{K} \Gamma (V)< \infty$

Let $V\subset A^n$  be a nonempty variety. Then $I(V)$  is a prime ideal in $K[X_{1},\ldots,X_{n}]$ so 
$K[X_{1},\ldots,X_{n}]/I(V)$ is a domain. We let $\Gamma (V)=K[X_{1},\ldots,X_{n}]/I(V)$, and call it the coordinate ring of $V$ .

Comment: No offense, but I suggest you review absolute basics before posting at here.

Comment: What is the context? The subvariety $x^2+y^2=0$ of $\mathbb R^2$ is reduced to a point but $\mathbb R[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2)$ is infinite-dimensional: what's  going on?

Comment: $K$ should be algebraically closed.

Answer (score 3):

I will give a few hints for the implications:

$i) \Rightarrow ii):$ If $V$ is point, then its ideal must be maximal. (...)

$ii) \Rightarrow iii):$ This one is kinda trivial. $K$ is a $K$-vector space over itself.

$iii) \Rightarrow i):$ If the coordinate ring is finite-dimensional, then it is artinian, hence dimension zero.